# Are Peyton Quinn's books appropriate for a 19 year old or are they beyond my level?

Tags: tae-kwon-do, self-defense, mixed-martial-arts, self-training

I know I'm a beginner at martial arts. I heard someone say on another site that they wished that they had heard of Peyton Quinn when they were 20. I think his [books](http://www.amazon.com/Peyton-Quinn/e/B001KISQ8E) sound very sophisticated.

Would someone doing WTF TKD still benefit from his novels at my age?

I won't be WTF in college because the teacher at my school will be ITF. Will it make a difference or could I read one of his books now and benefit?

Comment: I looked at the link you provided; I didn't see any novels. Books, but no novels.

Comment: @MarkC.Wallace: Ah, that could have been my edit.  I looked Peyton Quinn on amazon as I had no idea what he was or what he was writing.

Comment: If you follow the link you provided to amazon, you can see previews of at least some of his books - I've just spent 20 minutes browsing one (there's a "Surprise Me" link that jumps around showing a few pages here and there, which works well enough for reviewing a book like this)... looks quite reasonable overall - I don't see any reason you should be concerned unless you've been raised in a monastery and never encountered the F word before. ;-)

Answer (score 4):

**Yes, no, maybe...** It all depends on what you mean by "appropriate".

First, the themes and matters discussed in the book are suitable for an adult.  If you were a teenager or child, things might be different but at 19 you should have the matturity to read whatever you chose.

Second, should you follow the advice given (if any) in the books is up to you.  I would take it with a large grain of salt. Some of it might be good, some might be misguided, and some might be just plain stupid. If you do not possess critical thinking as a skill, it is high time you did!

Thirdly, if there are any training regimes within the book, I would urge caution in following them. They might be very suitable for him but not for you.  Again, refer to critical thinking and your best judgement. The latter should include talking to medical and sport professionals.

Finally, more often than not, *reading expands your knowledge which is always a good thing*.

Comment: Did you mean 'expands' in that last sentence?

Comment: @THelper: Dog damned dyslexia!!! Thank you. ^_~